# How to override/theme suggest webform composite element table?

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

I have created an implementation of

```
hook_theme_suggestions_table_alter()
```

in my THEMENAME.theme file:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme_suggestions_table_alter().
 */

function ncon_bs_theme_suggestions_table_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
    if (isset($variables['attributes']['data-drupal-selector'])){
        if ($variables['attributes']['data-drupal-selector'] == "edit-contact-person-comp-items"){
            $suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '--contact_person_comp_items_table';
        }
    }
}
```

I see that template suggestion is correctly added to my suggested templates:

[image: override webform composite element table]

But template file ('table--contact-person-comp-items-table.html.twig') is not loaded. Instead the default 'table.html.twig' is loaded.

So how to override template suggestion to webform composite element table?

Comment: The problem was in the suggestion name:

$suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '--contact_person_comp_items_table'

must be

$suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '__contact_person_comp_items_table'

So it's not webfirm module related.

Comment: You could answer your own question for those of us searching for solution.